# How to generate characters using ASCII values

Tags: java, random, ascii

For part of my program, I am trying to ask the user for input on generating a number of random characters. I have already done this with integers and doubles, how would I do this for characters using ASCII values? Would I use the same format as I did for generating integers (Shown in code)?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class NewNumberCharacter {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create a Scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Ask the user to enter in the command: integer, double, or character
    System.out.println("What do you want to generate, integer, double, or character?");

    // Prompt the user to enter a string, or command, then follow the prompts
    String command = input.nextLine();

    if(command.equals("character")){
        System.out.println("How many characters would you like generated?");

    int numcharacter = input.nextInt();

    RandomDataGenerator.random(numcharacter);
    }
    if (command.equals("integer")){
        System.out.println("What is the upper limit and lower limit of the integers you want to generate?");  

    int maxn1 = input.nextInt();
    int minn2 = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("How many integers do you want to generate?");
    int numinteger = input.nextInt();

      RandomDataGenerator.random(minn2,maxn1,numinteger); //Call the method
    }
    if (command.equals("double")){
        System.out.println("What is the upper limit and lower limit of the doubles you want to generate?");

    double maxn3 = input.nextDouble();
    double minn4 = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("How many doubles do you want to generate?");

    int numdouble = input.nextInt();

    RandomDataGenerator.random(maxn3,minn4,numdouble);
    }
}
}class RandomDataGenerator {

public static int random(int maxn1, int minn2, int numinteger){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < numinteger ; i++ ) {  
        System.out.println(maxn1 + (int)(Math.random()* minn2));    
    }    
    return 0;   
}
public static double random(double maxn3, double minn4, int numdouble){

    for (int i = 0; i < numdouble; i++){
       Random r = new Random();
       System.out.println(minn4 + (maxn3- minn4) * r.nextDouble()); 
    }
    return 0;
}
public static String random(int numcharacter){
    for (int i = 0; i < numcharacter;  i++){
        System.out.println();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

**UpdateV2**

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class NewNumberCharacter {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create a Scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Ask the user to enter in the command: integer, double, or character
    System.out.println("What do you want to generate, integer, double, or character?");

    // Prompt the user to enter a string, or command, then follow the prompts
    String command = input.nextLine();

    if(command.equals("character")){
        System.out.println("Enter in an ASCII value for the character" + 
                "\n 33 to 47 for special characters" +
                "\n 65 to 90 for uppercase letters" + 
                "\n 97 to 102 for lowercase letters");

        int ascii1 = input.nextInt();
        int ascii2 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("How many characters would you like generated?");

    int numcharacter = input.nextInt();

    RandomDataGenerator.random(ascii1,ascii2,numcharacter);
    }
    if (command.equals("integer")){
        System.out.println("What is the upper limit and lower limit of the integers you want to generate?");  

    int maxn1 = input.nextInt();
    int minn2 = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("How many integers do you want to generate?");
    int numinteger = input.nextInt();

      RandomDataGenerator.random(minn2,maxn1,numinteger); //Call the method
    }
    if (command.equals("double")){
        System.out.println("What is the upper limit and lower limit of the doubles you want to generate?");

    double maxn3 = input.nextDouble();
    double minn4 = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("How many doubles do you want to generate?");

    int numdouble = input.nextInt();

    RandomDataGenerator.random(maxn3,minn4,numdouble);
    }
}
}
class RandomDataGenerator {

public static int random(int maxn1, int minn2, int numinteger){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < numinteger ; i++ ) {  
        System.out.println(maxn1 + (int)(Math.random()* minn2));    
    }    
    return 0;   
}
public static double random(double maxn3, double minn4, int numdouble){

    for (int i = 0; i < numdouble; i++){
       Random r = new Random();
       System.out.println(minn4 + (maxn3- minn4) * r.nextDouble()); 
    }
    return 0;
}
public static char randChar(int ascii1 , int ascii2 , int numcharacter) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numcharacter; i++){
        Random r = new Random();
    }
     return(char)(Random.nextInt(ascii1-ascii2+1) + ascii1);
}
}
```

Comment: Why ASCII? This is 2014. Why not use Unicode code points?

Comment: My instructor told me to use ASCII...idk why. I am aware of unicode.

Comment: You should start by indenting properly your code, it will be easier to read, by you and the other users.

Comment: I did Ctrl + K, what else should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You would do it in a similar way. First of all, you need to learn about characters. Lookup keywords like *ASCII table* and *Unicode*.
Then select an alphabet from which you want the random characters. Printing random Chinese characters is a bit different from printing random Latin characters. Also, printing random Latin characters depends on whether you want to print them just from the base alphabet or whether you want to include additional characters from specific scripts, i.e. German Umlauts and German sz ligature.

The following example demonstrates how to create a String of random characters for uppercase Latin characters.

```
private static final Random random = new Random();
public static String random(final int numChars) {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < numChars; i++) {
        sb.append((char) (random.nextInt(26) + 'A'));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

By the way, you may want to rethink a few things about your program:

- You might want to return the computed value(s) instead of printing them in the functions.
- You might want to move the `System.out.println()` out of the functions to the caller.
- You might want to not generate a new random number generator in every loop iteration. One global for yourself should be enough.

Comment: I want to include special characters as well which include: ! “ # $ % & ` ( ) * + ‘ - . /  Would I have to create a separate thing for that

Comment: @blue1artic if you want a wider range of characters, use a number bigger than 26, and possibly a different character to add.  Do you know what range of ASCII you want?

Comment: "\n 33 to 47 for special characters" +
"\n 65 to 90 for uppercase letters" + 
"\n 97 to 102 for lowercase letters");

Comment: @PeterLawrey What I'm trying to do now is ask the user for ASCII range that they want to have, get a random ASCII value, then convert it into characters and display. My updated code is edited in the original question

Answer (score 0):

If you need a random range you can do

```
static final Random rand = new Random();
public static char randChar(char first, char last) {
     return (char)(rand.nextInt(last-first+1) + first);
}
```

Comment: It says "non-static method nextInt(int) cannot be referenced from a static context" as an error message.

Comment: @blue1artic in that case you haven't copied the code correctly. See this example, which compiles ok http://ideone.com/U4EnXN

Comment: I can make an update of the code that I tried putting in, can you see what I did wrong?

Comment: @blue1artic What does you IDE suggest is the problem?  Which line is it complaining about?  What is the error?

Comment: in this line: "return(char)(Random.nextInt(ascii1-ascii2+1) + ascii1);"

Comment: @blue1artic Yes.  `Random` is a class and this won't work, which why I used `rand` which is a field.

Comment: it says that it cannot find the symbol for rand

Comment: @blue1artic did you add a field called `rand`?

Comment: now it makes the "nextInt" have a cannot find symbol error.

Comment: @blue1artic did you make it a `Random` like in the code in the answer?

Comment: The code in the answer compiles and I suggest you copy the code.  When you have it working you can change it to taste.

Comment: I cannot copy and paste the code correctly, it's not working for me.

Comment: @blue1artic I provided a link which showed that it worked.  What do you mean "It's not working"?

Comment: static final gives me an error, rand.nextInt says that the symbol cannot be found.